# How many monitors can I connect to the Asus Rog Strix Z490-G Gaming (WiFi)

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, motherboard, asus

I want to buy an Asus Rog Strix Z490-G Gaming (Wi-Fi). My question is whether I can connect two or more monitors simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard has a DisplayPort 1.4 port. You can therefore daisy-chain DisplayPort compatible monitors, but the count depends on the resolution (limited by bandwidth)

[image: Display resolution Maximum number of monitors 1680 x 1050 5 1920 x 1080 4 2560 x 1600 2 3840 x 2160 (Ultra HD, 4K) or 4096 x 2160 (4K x 2K) 1]

But; given you're buying a gaming motherboard, I am assuming you will then add a discrete graphics card. When that happens, your maximum monitor count will change.